# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n!}}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory

I need to show that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n!}}$ is irrational.

Tried the same methods as proving for $e$ and $\sin{1}$ and such but it doesn't work for me as $n$ is in the power.

Would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: I hope you meant $n!$ at the exponent.

Comment: @IdanDaniel Look at the way b00n he T edited it.  You have to put the exponent in braces.

Comment: Yeah, in the power. Thanks for the edit

Comment: Hint: if it were rational, its binary representation would be eventually periodic.

Comment: Look up Liouville numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence - but other hints and solutons suggest  there are easier ways.

Comment: Hint: $|\frac{p}{q}-\frac{m}{n}| \ge \frac{1}{nq}$ for any positive distinct rationals. So if by contradiction you would get a rational $\frac{p}{q}$, cutting the series at high enough $n$ so $2^{(n+1)!}$ overwhelms $q$ should immediately give you the required contradiction

Comment: But this is true in general.  Let $b$ be a positive integer and $b>1$.  A real number $x$ is rational if and only if the base-$b$ representation of $x$ is periodic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Step 1. Do a proof by contradiction. Assume it's equal to $p/q$,.

Step 2. Multiply both sides by $q$.

Step 3. Multiply both sides by $2^{K!}$, for some fixed $K$. (We will choose $K$ later.)

Step 4. you should have an equation of the form
$$
\text{Integer} = \text{Integer} + \text{infinite sum starting from term $k = K$}.
$$
Ignore the parts that are integers, and so that the remaining infinite sum is between $0$ and sum bound -- for example, try to find an upper bound by noting that $2^{k!}$ is, at the very least, greater than or equal to $2^k$.

Step 5. Now you have a bound on something that is supposed to be an integer. Choose $K$ so that the thing is bounded between $0$ and $1$. Then it can't be an integer, so you are done.